# Aprendizados em JavaScript e NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Senhores, gostaria da ajuda de vocês pra entender o funcionamento de promises e async/await. Sou novato na linguagem e com muito custo entendi o funcionamento de callbacks. Alguém poderia me ajudar a traduzir o código abaixo pra promises?

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const connConfig = require('./dbConfig')
const connection = mysql.createConnection(connConfig.config.default)

const start = (query, arrayReturned) => {
    searchMenu(query, createArrayMenu,(options)=>{
        arrayReturned(options)
    })
}

const createArrayMenu = (row)=>{
    const options = []
    for (let index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {
        options[index] = [row[index].id_main_option,row[index].ds_main_option]
    }
    return options
}

const searchMenu = (query, getResults, transformResults)=>{
    connection.connect()
    connection.query(query,(err, results)=>{
        if(err) throw err
        transformResults(getResults(results))
    })
    connection.end()
}

module.exports = (query, test)=>{start(query, test)}
```

Comment: Você pode ler [este artigo](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br) (em português), que é uma excelente introdução ao tema. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você quer fazer algum tipo de requisição ou ação que demande mais tempo que o normal (chamar uma API, por exemplo), você precisa configurar se essa ação será necessária para os próximos funcionamentos ou não. É ai que entra as palavrinhas assíncrono e síncrono.

*Assíncrono*: É quando você quer o resultado da ação, mas não é necessário para os outros escopos do programa. Caso seja necessária fazer algo logo após a ação ser terminada, é possível usar Promises. Promises ou "promessas" é exatamente o que o nome diz, uma promessa de que, quando a ação terminar, será executado um código. A promise mais comum é a **.then**.
  Para criar um função assíncrona no javascript, basta colocar ***async*** na frente da função, e, quando desejar algo assíncrono na função, basta usar **await** antes da ação.

*Síncrono*: É usado para executar códigos em sequência, sendo um dependente do outro

Comment: Muito obrigado Murilo! A teoria foi bem esclarecedora!!!